# Question about handwritten numbers recognition with limited data set

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a an assignment to make a classifier for hand-written numbers with a limited data set of 500 samples.
I am currently using python, I tried sklearn SVC with linear classifier and I got an accuracy of about 80%. I also tried KNN with 13 neighbors and got a max of 81% accuracy.
I need to get to at least 90% accuracy. What are your suggestions that would help with training (adding noise? what distribution? / tilting the pictures with 90 degrees? Maybe cross validating over different parameters... etc).

Edit:
To clarify the main challenge:
I have to reach an accuracy of more that 90% with only using 500 samples, I can play around with the samples however I want to extend the data but I am not allowed to use external samples.

Comment: Try an SVM with a Gaussian instead of a linear kernel.

Comment: I used rbf kernel, and did cross-validation over different values of C and gamma, but the accuracy stayed low. Linear kernel gave the highest accuracy but capped at 80%.

Comment: Have you read the literature on classifiers for handwritten digits using MNIST?  There are dozens of papers, which a quick websearch can turn up, which describe a variety of techniques.  Also, please edit the question with clarifications rather than leaving them in the comments -- we want questions to stand on their own, so people don't have to read the comments to understand the question and what approaches you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you the following:

1. Adding a little bit of noise such as blurring
2. Transforming the images. You can rotate or stretch a bit, but make sure you don't change too much to change 6 to 9 or o to 0.

You can look at the following tutorials:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177744/how-does-perspective-transformation-work-in-pil
- http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html
- http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm